# VB - Convert RGB String to "nearest" Colorname

Tags: vb.net

I made an application which detects colors of images.
It outputs the colors as RGB Code, for instace R=23, G=44, B=109

These RGB codes should now be converted to rough color names ("Blue", "White", "Yellow") and so on, every color that "looks like" blue should be simpely defined as "blue".

Thank you :)

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: Yeah I know but I didn't try anything cause I don't have any idea how to start

Comment: Your question will be closed, unanswered, because it's too broad. If you "don't have any idea how to start", you're asking in the wrong place; you really need to know how to define the problem and define an "attack" on it before we can help you.

Comment: For example, how do you define "looks blue"?  More to the point, how should the _computer_ define "looks blue"? When you can answer questions like that, you will have a possible path of "attack" on the problem, and perhaps you can then write some code to test it - at which point you will probably be better able to articulate the nature of your problem, so that the SO community _can_ help you. Or maybe you'll even discover you don't need our help...

Answer (score 1):

Here are two classes that might produce the results you want.  Did not spend much time since you did not provide much to begin with.

```
Public Class LooksLikeColor
    Private _color As Color
    Public Sub New(colorToTest As Color) 'i.e.colorToTest = Color.FromArgb(23, 44, 109)
        Me._color = colorToTest
    End Sub

    Public distList As New List(Of ColorDistance)
    Public minDist As Double
    Public maxDist As Double
    Public avgDist As Double

    Private Sub DistanceFromList(ColorList As IEnumerable(Of Color))
        Me.distList.Clear()
        For Each c As Color In ColorList
            Dim foo As New ColorDistance(c, Me._color)
            Me.distList.Add(foo)
        Next
        Me.distList = Me.distList.OrderBy(Function(d) d._distance).ToList

        Me.minDist = Me.distList.Min(Function(d) d._distance)
        Me.maxDist = Me.distList.Max(Function(d) d._distance)
        Me.avgDist = Me.distList.Average(Function(d) d._distance)
    End Sub

    Public Sub ComputeDistanceKnownColors()
        Me.DistanceFromList(From kc In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(System.Drawing.KnownColor)) Select Color.FromName(kc.ToString))
    End Sub

    Public Sub ComputeDistanceFromList(Optional ColorList As List(Of Color) = Nothing)
        If ColorList Is Nothing Then
            Dim clrs() As Color = {Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue, Color.Yellow, Color.Cyan, Color.Magenta}
            Me.DistanceFromList(clrs)
        Else
            Me.DistanceFromList(ColorList)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function SelDist(dist As Double) As List(Of ColorDistance)
        Dim rv As New List(Of ColorDistance)
        rv = (From d In Me.distList Where d._distance <= dist Select d).ToList
        Return rv
    End Function
End Class

Public Class ColorDistance
    ''' <summary>
    ''' known color
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public _r1 As Color
    Public _r2 As Color
    Public _distance As Double = 0.0R

    Public Sub New(knwn As Color, tstColor As Color)
        Me._r1 = knwn
        Me._r2 = tstColor
        Me._distance = ((CInt(Me._r2.R) - CInt(Me._r1.R)) ^ 2)
        Me._distance += ((CInt(Me._r2.G) - CInt(Me._r1.G)) ^ 2)
        Me._distance += ((CInt(Me._r2.B) - CInt(Me._r1.B)) ^ 2)
        Me._distance = Math.Sqrt(Me._distance)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And some code to test with

```
    Dim c As Color = Color.FromArgb(23, 44, 109)
    Dim foo As New LooksLikeColor(c)
    foo.ComputeDistanceFromList()

    Dim cdl As List(Of ColorDistance) = foo.SelDist(foo.avgDist)
    Debug.WriteLine("")
    For Each d As ColorDistance In cdl
        Debug.WriteLine(d._r1.Name)
    Next
```

Use the debugger to follow the code.  Make adjustments as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be define a map of your colors (BLUE, WHITE, YELLOW) associating the labels with specific RGB values, and the you can use one of the mertics of [color distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference)

You can take the euclidean distance, then calculate the nearest color minimizing this metric. Obviously this won't have perfect results but could be acceptable for you.